# How to instansiate a IController in ASP.NET MVC 4 (Preview) so IController.ValidateModel works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the need to manually instansiate some controllers and therefore have this code:

```
var controller = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AccountController), 
                 repository) as AccountController;
```

In the AccountController I have a method similar to this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ApiJsonResult LogOn(LogOnAccountDto model)
{
     ValidateModel(model);
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
      //...
     }
}
```

I want my ModelState.IsValid to work, so therefore I call ValidateModel and pass it the model.

This fails, apparently because the controlContext isn't set.
I get this error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: controllerContext  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: controllerContext

So, how can I manually instansiate a IController in code - so that "everything" works?

Thanks in advance.

**So, why do I need this?**
I'm playing around with some architecture and game logic ideas for an "online strategy game".

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 (Preview) application, which is my web version of the game. The idea is that the game should also be played on devices like Windows Phone, iPhone etc via NATIVE apps.
Therefore I need some API for my game (some kind of REST service which communicate via http/json). 
As this API will be the public interface for the game, all the game logic will of course be located in side this API.

Therefore I want to use this API from both the "web version" and the "mobile version" of the game. 
I have implemented this API as an Area inside ASP.NET MVC 4 (Preview). My first though were to actually do httpwebrequest from my "web version" to the API so I were using the API EXACTLY as the "mobile version" would. 
But then I thought, that it might be better to actually just instansiate the controllers manually to avoid all the json/web-calling overhead I would get from calling the API the "right way".

So that's why I'm here now, I want to instansiate my controllers manually in code, because I want to use the exact logic in them.

Makes sense?
If you have a better idea please let me know - I'm doing this this for the learning of it, not produce a real product - at least thats not the goal right now - right now I'm just trying to learn some new stuff :)

Comment: You oughta be doing something extremely wrong with your design if you ever need to manually instantiate a controller. I repeat: extremely wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question and explain why I need this. Just a second.

Comment: What do you mean by the `web version` of your game? Isn't this the ASP.NET MVC application itself?

Comment: Yep, the "web version" is the ASP.NET MVC 4 application itself. One of the reasons why I want to have the API as a part of the actually MVC application, is that I need to be able to run multiple, seperated, versions of this game at the same time.

Comment: like:
s1.mygame.com - for this the api will be at s1.mygame.com/api

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `ValidateModel` directly.

At least I never needed to call it directly in any of my code and I haven't seen any examples which would call it either.

You can use the attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to control how your model is validated.

Let me give you an example, copy-pasted from some working code.

The model class:
(Basically just a DTO, nothing special.)

```
public class ArticleModel
{
    public ArticleModel()
    {
        CategoryIds = new List<int>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field mandatory!")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field mandatory!")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public bool RefreshDate { get; set; }

    public List<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action:
(Instantiates an object for the ORM and saves it to the database.)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[SiteAuthorize(SiteAuthorization.SiteOwner)]
public ActionResult EditArticle(ArticleModel model)
{
    var article = Repository.Retrieve<Article>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id && x.Site == ColorfulUtility.CurrentSite);

    if (article == null)
        return RedirectToAction("ArticleList");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.RefreshDate)
            article.Date = DateTime.Now;

        article.Title = model.Title.SimpleTextToSafeHtml();
        article.Text = model.Text.RichTextToSafeHtml();
        article.Summary = model.Summary.RichTextToSafeHtml();

        foreach (var category in ColorfulUtility.CurrentSite.ArticleCategories)
        {
            if (!article.Categories.Contains(category) && model.CategoryIds.Contains(category.Id))
            {
                article.Categories.Add(category);
            }
            else if (article.Categories.Contains(category) && !model.CategoryIds.Contains(category.Id))
            {
                article.Categories.Remove(category);
            }
        }

        Repository.Flush();

        return RedirectToAction("ArticleList");
    }

    return View("CreateArticle", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm actually aware of the DataAnnotations, atually these are already set on my model. ValidateModel is validating against these DataAnnotations.

Comment: But the more I think about it, the more I see that I might want to change my design here, and simply take the API out in it's own project and then do webrequests against it, like all other clients would. Just thought I could take a shortcut here and make it all less complex, but seems like the opposite is happening as it's not easy to instansiate IControllers by your self :)